# PSQL PG_DUMP with su - postgres

Tags: bash, postgresql, ssh

I'm trying to write a bash script that would allow me to:

1) Login into ssh root account

2) If logged then log in as postgres

3) If logged as postgres then pg_dumb of my db to my local db

My code looks:

```
ssh root@myhost

user = `root`

if [ "$user" == "root" ]; then
  su - postgres
fi

user = `postgres`

if [ "$user" == "postgres" ]; then
  pg_dump my_user_name my_db | psql my_db2
fi
```

Before running my script I've created locally a new user **my_db** with --owner **my_db2**, so there shouldn't be problems with copying the dump to my local db.

But the problem is that when I run this script all I get is just login to ssh root and nothing more happens. Just getting /root

No next procedure.

Anyone would help with this ? Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You can directly fire command as a postgres user from root prompt. See below:

su - postgres -c 'pg_dump source-db | psql target-db'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
user="root"

if [ "$user" == "root" ]; then
su - postgres
fi
```